# iOS Safari - Image not visible until changes made in web inspector

Tags: ios, safari, web-inspector

The problem is that I have an image element that should be displayed. The CSS necessary for displaying the image is there, and yet, it is hidden. But for some reason if I toggle **ANY** CSS value in the web inspector (not just for the element in question) the image will display. The behavior is the same on Xcode simulator and on the actual device.

What could cause this? I'm hoping the answer will help me understand why the image isn't appearing to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily an answer to my question, **but** it is the answer to the underlying problem. Hopefully it will help anyone else having the same problem.

The reason why the image wasn't initially displaying was because the `vw` and `vh` values used to set the images's container element's `width` and `height` were not initially calculating correctly leaving the image with computed values of `width: 0` and `height: 16px`. I fixed this by using media queries to target iPads and use static `px` values instead.

I still don't understand why web inspector was behaving the way it was, but this was the solution to the actual problem.